# Open VisualForce Report from Account Page Layout to new Window with filtered data

Tags: visualforce

I have a simple VF page that opens a Chart on a Account Page Layout;

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
<script type="text/javascript">
function Test(){
var url = '/00Oj0000004KjPM';
window.parent.location.replace(url);
}
</script>
<apex:outputLink onclick="Test();">
    <analytics:reportChart cacheResults="false" reportId="00Oj0000004KjPM"
        filter="{column:'FK_ACC_ID',operator:'equals',value:'{!Account.Id}'}"
        size="small">
    </analytics:reportChart>  
   </apex:outputLink>
</apex:page>
```

This works ok but I cannot get the report to open in a 'new' window and the report that does open is not filtered by the Account id.

Any thoughts or suggestions is alwys appreciated.

Regards,
M

Comment: `window.parent.location.replace(url);` read up on your DOM model.

Comment: Could you use a custom link instead ? Create a report using the criteria of Id and add the link to the Account page.

Comment: Ok.  Removing this syntax helped but it still open in the same window. Modified and was able to get a new window to open but URL is incorrect.The interesting thing is that when I click the chart the report looks correct.  But The report that opens in the new window states that the url does not exist.   The report originally does not have a filter on it.  I am filtering the report in the code.  Is that why the url is not opening correctly?                      <apex:outputLink onclick="window.open('/00Oj0000004KmzD/pv0={!Account.Id}','','width=500,height=500')">  What are my options?

Comment: I considered that since I may have 8 reports loading on the Account page which is causing the page to load slower. So will the link allow me to open to a new window? Will this render correctly on a mobile device(IOS)? Thanks for the suggestion. Michael